# Non-blocking Thrift Server in Python

Tags: python, nonblocking, thrift, thrift-protocol

In below code snippet, I am trying to make a non-blocking thrift server in python.

```
    # set handler to our implementation
    handler = ServiceHandler()

    processor = MyService.Processor(handler)
    transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port=port)
    tfactory = TTransport.TFramedTransport(transport)  
    pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()

    # set server
    server = TServer.TThreadedServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

    print 'Python Server has started listening on port ' + str(port)
    print '################################################'
    server.serve()
```

I am getting the following error when the python client attempts to connect the server having tyhe above code snippet. Could you please tell me what can be causing this error? Probably I am missing something.

```
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/thrift/server/TServer.py", line 114, in handle
    itrans = self.inputTransportFactory.getTransport(client)
    AttributeError: TFramedTransport instance has no attribute 'getTransport'
```

Comment: The above, error statememts are issued on the server side FYI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found some [working Thrift code](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@t@h@thrift-examples-HEAD@server@PythonServer.py/53/thrift.server.TServer.TThreadedServer.serve/python) and it looks like your tfactory needs to be a TBufferedTransportFactory and not a TBufferedTransport instance.

```
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
```